# Bologna Process - Equivalence note in European Supplement

Tags: grades, europe, grading, bologna-process

I recently graduated from a MSc in Spain.

When applying for PhD abroad I discovered the equivalence system in place in order to "translate" my grades here into a standard one, as part of the Bologna process.

The system in place in Spain is the following for the MSc, a grade over 10 :

- From 5 to 6.9 : "Satisfactory"
- From 7 to 8.9 : "Very Good"
- From 9 to 10.0 : "Excellent"
- "Honors" is given on **exceptional** occasion.

I insist on the **exceptional** occasion. On any course, there cannot be more than two students with honors, and often none is given.

The "European standard" grade is a grade from 1 to 4. It looks like each country decided for the equivalence system. And here is my issue, there are HUGE discrepancies between them. In Spain, they chose the following basic equivalence (see the [Royal Decree 1044/2003](https://www.boe.es/boe/dias/2003/09/11/pdfs/A33848-33853.pdf) for Spanish speaker):

- Satisfactory -> 1/4
- Very Good -> 2/4
- Excellent -> 3/4
- Honor -> 4/4

Meaning that even if you get a perfect score of 10/10 in an exam, this will only show as 3/4 in the European Supplement. That makes NO sense! Especially when you know that the same system in very different, in the UK for instance. I spoke with several teachers in UK and in Spain, and clearly the system is biased : From their own word, in the UK, a student with less than 3/4 will be regarded as "average" when applying for PhD, while in Spain, there are no simply no student with grades over 3/4 (at least this year at my uni) ! Again, words from Spanish teachers, here a student with around 2.5 grade will be considered as a very good profile.

The issue is that this EU system (from 1 to 4) is directly used as is by several processes of PhD and grant applications, inside and outside of Europe. Meaning that Spanish students are at a big disadvantage here.

> is this issue well known in Europe? Is there anything feasible in order to remedy it?

I don't fear long administrative process. I know that I can try explaining the issue every time I apply somewhere, but this wouldn't be true solution, as it is often not possible to communicate with PhD application's jury, and many students are not even aware of this.

> Also, does anyone knows where I could find the equivalence system for other countries? I would like to look at the topic further.